# Property 'foo' does not exist on type '[number, number, number]'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting this error

> Property 'foo' does not exist on type '[number, number, number]'

I don't understand why or how to fix this. Here's a [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/interview-exercise-4-newcombinelatest?file=src/app/app.component.ts) if you can help

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   new Observable();

   const foo = of(45);
   const bar = interval(2000);
   const baz = timer(1000);
   // const faz = from(1, 2, 3, 4);

   this.newCombineLatest = combineLatest(foo, bar, baz)
     .pipe(
       tap(res => {
         console.log(this.index++, "foo", res.foo, ", bar: ", res.bar);
       }),
       take(10)
     )
     .subscribe(() => {
       value => console.log(value);
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for [`combineLatest`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest) - the Observable output is an array with values that correspond to the latest emission of the ordinal observable inputs.

Arrays are numerically indexed, so `res` is an array of three numbers. It does not have object keys (except for the `length` property and array methods, etc.). More to the point, there is no way for JavaScript to know that your variable name is `foo` and that it should assign a property `foo` to the array.

Instead, use the numeric indices that correspond to the observable argument order:

```
console.log(this.index++, "foo", res[0], ", bar: ", res[1]);
```